# scatter3 - show x, y, z in certain way

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I would like to show the x, y, z axis like this (together with the scatter data):

[3D coord. system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCoord_system_CA_0.svg)

I tried to edit the graph using the GUI (e.g. trying to move the yaxis). I there any way to achieve this?

My basic code:

```
M = csvread('H:\Bla.csv', 1);

figure1 = figure;

% Create axes
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,'YAxisLocation','right','XAxisLocation','top',...
    'MinorGridLineStyle','none',...
    'GridLineStyle','-');
view(axes1,[-65.5 36]);
grid(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');

% Create scatter3
scatter3(M(:,1),M(:,2),M(:,3));

% Create xlabel
xlabel('X');

% Create ylabel
ylabel('Y');

% Create zlabel
zlabel('Z');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do something like this manually (you still need to add arrows):

```
x = line([0 100],[0,0],[0,0],'color','r');
y = line([0 0],[0,100],[0,0],'color','g');
z = line([0 0],[0,0],[0,100],'color','b']);
```

Or use some available FEX contributions:

- [TinyAxes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32168)
- [oaxes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30018)